# mongoose promise how to skip to next .then()

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise

I am implementing email verification with the following code

```
//1. find the verificationInfo
VerificationInfo.findOne({user: req.user}).exec(function(err, verificationInfo) {
    if (err)
        return next(err)

    if (verificationInfo) {
        //2. if already have verification info
        var verificationLink = helper.urlWithQuery(req.baseUrl + '/verify', {token: verificationInfo.token})
        helper.sendEmail(email, 'verify your email', 'click the link: ' + verificationLink, function(err) {
            if (err)
                return next(helper.getGeneralError('unable to send email'))
            res.json({success: 'successfully sent email'})
        })
    }
    else {
        //3. no such verification info, create a new one
        var newVerificationInfo = new VerificationInfo()
        newVerificationInfo.user = req.user
        newVerificationInfo.token = helper.getUUID()
        newVerificationInfo.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                return next(err)
            var verificationLink = helper.urlWithQuery(req.baseUrl + '/verify', {token: newVerificationInfo.token})
            helper.sendEmail(email, 'verify your email', 'click the link: ' + verificationLink, function(err) {
                if (err)
                    return next(helper.getGeneralError('unable to send email'))
                res.json({success: 'successfully sent email'})
            })
        })
    }
})
```

The send email part is duplicated. So I change this code to use promise like this

```
VerificationInfo.findOne({user: req.user}).exec()
    .then(function(verificationInfo) {
        if (! verificationInfo) {
            var newVerificationInfo = new VerificationInfo()
            newVerificationInfo.user = req.user
            newVerificationInfo.token = helper.getUUID()
            req.token = newVerificationInfo.token
            return newVerificationInfo.save()
        }
        else {
            req.token = verificationInfo.token
            //TODO: HOW TO GET TO THE NEXT .then()
        }
    })
    .then(function() {
        var verificationLink = helper.urlWithQuery(req.baseUrl + '/verify', {token: req.token})
        helper.sendEmail(email, 'verify your email', 'click the link: ' + verificationLink, function(err) {
            if (err)
                return next(helper.getGeneralError('unable to send email'))
            res.json({success: 'successfully sent email'})
        })
    })
    .then(null, function(err) {
        return next(err)
    })
```

As indicated in my comment, If the verificationInfo is already there, How can i go to the next .then()?

Comment: What happens when you run this code? From what I can see it should already go to the next `then` (the one that will send the email) without any changes.

Comment: @victorkohl `.then()` is not called somehow

Comment: @OMGPOP: Something else must be wrong then. Currently, your promise resolves with `undefined`, and the next `then` callback would be invoked.

Comment: To make the code more like the original version, you might try delivering the `token` via the promise chain, rather than as a property of `req`. To do so, you will need an inner chain `newVerificationInfo.save().then(...)`. If that throws an error, then you will have discovered `.save()` not to be thenable, which might be the original issue.

Comment: @OMGPOP are you sure it is going to the else block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in other places. I have decided to remove the existence check. If user send multiple requests, I just create a new one since it will get expired soon and deleted automatically by mongoose